# Adjective + Tokoro Ga

Tags: usage, particles

I've been trying to translate the following sentence:

> 外傷 は 無かった けど、どこ か 具合 が 悪い ところ が あったり する？

The part I think I have a problem with is:

> 具合 が 悪い ところ が
>   guai ga warui tokoro ga

I believe I picked up the "somewhere"/"anywhere" and the *-tari suru* form of the verb *au* correctly. However, I can't put it together with the two がs and the ところ after an adjective to make sense of the whole sentence.

Does the ところ serves here purely as a noun? The rules I found for it are always with Verbs.

Which が indicates the subject of the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case ところ is being used literally ("place"), rather than in order to nominalize the preceding clause. So "具合が悪い" is actually modifying ところ, making the sentence mean something along the lines of "There aren't any external wounds, but does anywhere (どこか+ところがあったりする) feel bad/off (具合が悪い)?"